# How to draw indented(concave) solid polygon in cocos2dx

Tags: c++, ios, cocos2d-x, draw

I need to draw indented(concave) solid polygon with some vertices.
I use

```
void HelloWorld::draw(void)
{ 
    CCPoint vertices[5] = {ccp(200, 200), ccp(400, 400), ccp(200, 600), ccp(500, 600), ccp(500, 200)};
    ccDrawSolidPoly(vertices, 5, ccc4f(0.7f, 0.7f, 0.7f, 0.5f));
}
```

And get Rectangle with triangle inside.
But I expect indented(concave) solid polygon as in the picture

[image: obtained and expected]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `drawPolygon function in CCDrawNode`

```
void drawPolygon(CCPoint* verts, unsigned int count, const ccColor4F &fillColor,
                         float  borderWidth, const ccColor4F& borderColor)
```

here is an example

```
CCPoint vertices[5] = {ccp(200, 200), ccp(400, 400), ccp(200, 600), ccp(500, 600), ccp(500, 200)};
CCDrawNode* polygon = CCDrawNode::create();
//creating red polygon with thin black border
polygon->drawPolygon(vertices, 5, ccc4f(1, 0, 0, 1), 1, ccc4f(0, 0, 0, 1));
addChild(polygon);
```

I hope it works

Comment: try rearranging the vertices, now you're doing it clockwise, try to do counter clockwise

Comment: bad news for you. cocos2d doesn't support concave polygon (your expected result is concave). what you can do is dividing it into 2 non-concave polygons `{(200,200) (500,200) (500, 400) (400,400) } and {(400,400) (500, 400) (500,600) (200,600) }

Comment: Is there algorithm which can make this dividing? Because in real game there are a lot of points. Picture: http://i.stack.imgur.com/pvJuU.png

Comment: are you drawing it dynamically? If you need it so badly, they have something called `tessellation` (http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_tessellation.html). It's about dividing your polygon to many triangles. It's quite complicated, and I don't think cocos2dx supports it. It looks interesting to me, so if you really need it, I can try to help you

Comment: This algoritm interesting for me too, but it can spent a lot of time. I have deadline at project:) And will use polyline(list of lines) instead solidPolygon. Maybe in version 2 It will be needed this feature. Thank you for help:)

Answer (score 3):

Without modifications to Cocos2d engine you can achive the polygon of the desired form either by starting your array from ccp(400,400) or by adding one more point ccp(500,400)! And then your array of points should start from this point like in the picture I attach.

[image]

The reason for this is that cocos2d uses by default GL_TRIANGLE_FAN flag while drawing complex polygons. This means that all the points in the triangles in your polygon will be built relative to the first point in the array of points.

You can go to CCDrawNode.cpp file and replace this flag by GL_TRIANGLE_SPLIT. To know more just google these two flags.

Comment: This is brilliant.  I've read this answer before but today the penny dropped and I suddenly saw that by simply changing the first point to being in the middle of a side of my polygon, it would achieve what you've said.  Awesome, thanks!